# Different methods of adding menu support to custom theme

Tags: functions, menus, theme-customizer

I Just want to know the different methods for menu support in my custom theme. I am in a process of converting HTML to WordPress theme and want to make menu's dynamic using codes in funtion.php and header.php. What are the alternative available. In how many ways it can be done . Which is the best among that ??

Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are really only 2 ways to do this in wordpress.  The first, which I'll call the "old way" uses [`wp_list_pages()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_list_pages/) and I would generally not recommend it for menus.

The second, which I would say is much better is using [`register_nav_menu()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_nav_menu/).  To use that, add this to the top of your functions.php file.

```
function register_theme_menus() {
  register_nav_menu('main-menu',__( 'Main Menu' ));
}
add_action( 'init', 'register_theme_menus' );
```

That snippet creates 1 menu called "Main Menu".  You can repeat `register_nav_menu()` for as many different menus as you'd like.  After adding that you'll see an option in the WP backend under "Appearance" called "Menus" where you'll be able to add items to the menu.

To display the menu, call [`wp_nav_menu(array('menu'=>'main-menu'))`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_nav_menu/) wherever you want to place the menu.  Make sure to style it.  This creates menus of this format:

```
<ul class="menu" id="menu-main-menu">
    <li class="menu-item"></li>
</ul>
```

You can add styles to those to style the menu.  There is also `.current-menu-item` on the li that holds the current page.

There are lots more styles to play with on here, the easiest way to see them all is to create a menu and then "view source" on the menu that was generated.

Comment: Thank You!!! can you please share how to style it  ?

Comment: @Mike, I added some extra styling info.  That is a big topic all on its own so I really only scratched the surface.